# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Integer com.dyplom.repository

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have this query in my `StudentRepository` and I suppose that some mistake in the query:

```java
@Query("SELECT Student.groupId FROM Student WHERE Student.studentLogin=?1")
Integer getGroupIdByStudentLogin(String studentLogin);
```

But still can't find solution to rewrite properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query syntax would be:

```
@Query("SELECT s.groupId FROM Student s WHERE s.studentLogin=?1")
Integer getGroupIdByStudentLogin(String studentLogin);
```

See [*The Java Persistence Query Language*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) for more info.